# C - Reading from a file issue with the last line

Tags: c, newline

The expected input to my program for my assignment is something like 
`./program "hello" < helloworld.txt`. The trouble with this however is that I must analyse every line that is in the program, so I have used the guard for the end of a line as:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n') {
    /*stuff will be done*/
```

However, my problem with this is that if the `helloworld.txt` file contains:

```
hello
world
```

It will only read the first line(up to the second last line if there were to be more lines).

For this to be fixed, I have to strictly make a new line such that `helloworld.txt` looks something like:

```
hello
world
//
```

Is there another way around this?

Comment: Did your original file have a newline at the end of `world`? Some editors add those, some don't. Perhaps "do stuff" on EOF as well as `\n`?

Comment: @DevSolar I'm just assuming the worst in which the person marking it uses a test file that does not have a new line.

Comment: But in that case you have read characters *but not done "stuff"* when you encounter EOF (and presumably exit). That's why your last line doesn't show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your algorithm. Instead of:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        /* stuff will be done */
    } else {
        /* buffer the c character */
    }
}
```

Do:

```
do {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == '\n' || c == EOF) {
        /* do stuff with the buffered line */
        /* clear the buffered line */
    } else {
        /* add the c character to the buffered line */
    }
} while (c != EOF);
```

But please note that you shouldn't use the value of the `c` variable if it is `EOF`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-structure your program so it can "do stuff" on `EOF`, if it has read any characters since the previous linefeed. That way, a non-terminated final line will still be processed.